# Using Props in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass the raffle id in to the modal, I am sure this would work or do I need to use javascript for to pass the id?

```
<div class="m-6 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-lg divide-y">
    @foreach ($raffles as $raffle)
        <div class="p-6">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900">{{ $raffle->title }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-input-label for="required_tickets" :value="__('Required Tickets')" />
                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $raffle->required_tickets }}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-input-label for="sold_tickets" :value="__('Sold Tickets')" />
                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $raffle->sold_tickets }}</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <x-input-label for="raffle_drawn" :value="__('Raffle Drawn')" />
                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $raffle->is_drawn ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <x-primary-button class="ml-3" x-data=""
                        x-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('open-modal', 'enter-draw-modal', { raffleId: {{ $raffle->id }} })">
                        {{ __('Enter Draw') }}
                    </x-primary-button>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    @endforeach
</div>

@props(['raffleId'])

        <x-modal {{ $attributes }}  name="enter-draw-modal">
            <div class="px-6 py-4">
                <div class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">
                    Enter Draw
                </div>

                <div class="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-600">
                    <!-- Add your content here -->
                    {{ $raffle->id }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-row justify-end px-6 py-4 bg-gray-100 text-right">
                <!-- Add your footer here -->
            </div>
        </x-modal>
```

the raffle details show on the blade template, just not passing the id to the modal

I have tried moving the modal around on the page (inside the loop) etc but of course to just loops through all the modals. Any assistance would be appreciated :)